# Can't compile .xsl into java class file

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have been trying to compile xslt file into java class and keep getting this errors. Not sure what I am doing wrong here:

> java com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Compile Hello.xsl
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:495)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:396)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:322)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:458)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Compile.main(Compile.java:145)
>   Compiler errors:
>     Could not compile stylesheet

Java version installed: 1.7.0_95. I cannot move to any other java flavor.

Here is my stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/hello-world">
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <TITLE></TITLE>
      </HEAD>
      <BODY>
        <H1>
          <xsl:value-of select="greeting"/>
        </H1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="greeter"/>
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="greeter">
    <DIV>from <I><xsl:value-of select="."/></I></DIV>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have checked the other posts related to this question, but the answer for those are solving the error I am getting.

Here is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hello-world>
   <greeter>An XSLT Programmer</greeter>
   <greeting>Hello, World!</greeting>
</hello-world>
```

Comment: I understand you are trying to transform your XML document to HTML content using XSLT and Java. If so, Can you post your XML?

Comment: You have to show us the Java code.  From the stack trace it looks like you passed a null pointer to the `TransformerFactory#newTransformer()` method.

Comment: I am using ' java com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Compile Hello.xsl ', not created any separate java class just using command line utility.

Comment: In java7, XMLSecurityManager is added in the Parser.java file under com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler package which is causing the NullPointerException. Is there any way to deal with this?